# Webpage import module instead of uisng "static" HTML, how do i get access to these module using BeautifulSoup

Tags: web-scraping, beautifulsoup

The website that i use for a project at my school doesn't consist of "static" html, it use a function to import module which contain the html code that I need for scraping, when I make a request to the website using BeautifulSoup, what i get in return is a HTML file that contain the script for the function  that import the HTML code ( I have it right here ). Any ideas on how i might get access to the actual HTML code ?

```
<script>
    webpack.import('modules/leaderboard/leaderboard').then(function (module) {
        new module.LeaderBoard('#id-606f76f', {});
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Can you share page URL?

Comment: sure, https://www.usopen.com/scoring.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All data comes from XHR. You can get it as

```
import requests

url = 'https://gripapi-static-pd.usopen.com/gripapi/leaderboard.json'
response = requests.get(url).json()
```

To print specific data, e.g. `"to par"` value for first player:

```
print(response['standings'][0]['toPar']['displayValue'])
```

`"Round 1"` value for second player:

```
print(response['standings'][1]['roundScores'][0]['score']['value'])
```

etc...

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help ! It works, may i ask how did you get the link to this page ? I mean this: https://gripapi-static-pd.usopen.com/gripapi/leaderboard.json

Comment: And one more question, the data from this link will be updated accordingly to the website right ?

Comment: @HUNG , you can do the following in your browser: 1) Press F12; 2) Switch to Network tab in dev console; 3) Select XHR sub-tab only; 4) Go to https://www.usopen.com/scoring.html; 5) Check requests that were sent by your browser (user Agent)...

Comment: @HUNG , all the data that you see on web-page is rendered based on data that comes from XHR, so yes, you'll get up-to-date data only